# Serve Flask applications like PHP scripts

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration, uwsgi, flask

On most webserver configurations, `.php` files are automatically processed when a user accesses a php file, using `php-fpm`.

I'd like to do a similar thing for Flask apps on my `nginx` server, so that when a user accesses a `.py` file or a directory with an `index.py` file, the Flask app is automatically run.

What config would be necessary for this, under a `nginx` server on Ubuntu?

Comment: This isn't how Python apps work. You need a wsgi interpreter, which is separate from nginx.

Comment: @EEAA Couldn't I configure `nginx` to automatically use a WSGI interpreter on a Python script, given certain static things like the main Flask instance being named `app`?

Comment: @EEAA It seems to me like the wsgi interpreter is roughly parallel to PHP's `php-fpm`, or am I mistaken?